# Preventing d3 chords from overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, chord-diagram

[**This demo**](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/chord-diagrams/coffee-from-files.html) (not my code) compares two different categories of items to each other, so -- unlike a chord diagram where any item can be connected to any other item -- coffee shops can't be connected to coffee shops and states can't be connected to states.

Some wedges look like this, if Dunkin' Donuts come first:

[image]

But other wedges look like this, if Starbucks has a higher value in the state:

[image]

Unnecessary overlap, in my opinion. The order of the elements shouldn't be determined by their value, but instead by the order of the elements on the left side -- that is, always Dunkin' first.

I see a sort happening in

```
 var chord = d3.layout.chord()
             .padding(.02)
             .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
```

but I'm not sure how I can specify a custom sort for the state elements. It makes sense to have the coffee shop subgroups sorted desc (or asc) but the states shouldn't get the same treatment.

How do we know if a chord is a state or not? It seems that information can be pulled by passing a chord to the `rdr` instance of the `chordRdr` function, which ties the `matrix`, which is what's being sorted, to meta-information from the `mmap` object.

How can I create a conditional subgroup sort?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't do it in d3.

This is how d3 performs the sort:

```
// Sort subgroups…
if (sortSubgroups) {
  subgroupIndex.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.sort(function(a, b) {
      return sortSubgroups(matrix[i][a], matrix[i][b]);
    });
  });
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/chord.js)

It will perform the sort for every subgroup.

The only way I can think of to make this work legitimately would be to have a custom copy of `d3.chord.layout()`, which can be found at the above link, if you want to toy with it.

Comment: Yes, good point. The `chord()` function doesn't know anything about the matrix map. It can only operate on the matrix of numbers. The sort function would also need the `mmap` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend actually using this [solution](http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/1e86c34932980874eb5f):

```
//all the values in matrix are integers
//we can track the numbers that are starbucks stores
//by adding a small decimal to them
matrix = matrix.map(function(row){
  return row.map(function(d, i){
    return d + (i == row.length - 1 ? 1e-7 : 0) })
})

//now we can do a lexicographic sort 
//first checking for the presence of a decimal and then size
var chord = d3.layout.chord()
    .sortSubgroups(function(a, b){
      if (a != Math.round(a)) return false
      if (b != Math.round(b)) return true
      return b < a ? -1 : b > a ? 1 : 0;
    })
```

Modifying `d3.layout.chord` or starting fresh with [something simpler](http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/408f41a4e4c721c5e1fb) that doesn't require a redundant matrix of values would probably work better in most situations.